# How to match null using Spark connector for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query a MongoDB collection using an aggregate function with the pyspark mongodb connector, but I can't perform a match to null.

I've tried this in the pipeline:

```
{'$match' : {'deleted_at': null}}
{'$match' : {'deleted_at': 'null'}}
{'$match' : {'deleted_at': None}}
{'$match' : {'deleted_at': False}}
{'$match' : {'deleted_at': 0}}
```

But nothing seems to work. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `df.filter($"deleted_at" === null)` with Spark SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can leverage filters pushdown in Spark (by default)

> When using `filter`s with DataFrames or the Python API, the underlying Mongo Connector code constructs an aggregation pipeline **to filter the data in MongoDB before sending it to Spark**.

[Spark-Mongo connector doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/python/filters-and-sql/)

### Python code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()

filtrDf = df.filter(df['deleted_at'] == 'null')

filtrDf.explain() // check for physical plan of this output
```

Comment: May be you can give a try with [query profiling tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) in mongo db. So that you can confirm Spark is building mongo db aggregation pipeline with filters.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution that allows me to avoid changing all the querys. The solution is to match the type like this:

```
{'$match' : 'deleted_at': { '$type': 10 }}
```

Because 10 correspond to type null